# How to handle images with webpack encore & assets

Tags: image, symfony, webpack, assets

so I seem to be a bit confused on how to work with images in webpack encore + assets.

I store all JS & CSS like this

```
/assets/js
/assets/css
...
```

With encore I can access them later from my **/public/build** folder - no issues there.

***Now I want to store some images (e.g. file upload).***

First idea was to store them inside a folder like **/assets/images**. But with the current settings & using assets I can only access files inside **/public/build** folder.

So I tried to use to **copyFiles** to copy everything from **/assets/images** to **/public/build/images**.

**But** this does ***not*** automatically copy my files (e.g. file upload to /assets/images/ does not copy it to /public/build - which is in order not accessible in my project). So I would need to run manually encore - which I don't want.

---

Second idea was to store the uploaded images directly inside /public/build/images **but** those files would be deleted when I run encore.

Next I disabled the webpack option **cleanupOutputBeforeBuild**, so images would not be deleted. But without this option the folder will be flooded by new JS & CSS Files everytime I run encore.

---

**What do I need?**

A solution to store my images either way in /assets folder & make them available for my project.

or

store the images directly in /public/build folder without encore deleting them nor flooding the folder with JS/CSS by disabling cleanupOutput Option.

---

Thanks in advance ~Syllz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution to my problem:**
Store the images into /public/images and not into the build folder - which will be deleted when running encore.

Answer (score 2):

**If u need to use it in JS, just require the file:**

```
// assets/app.js

import logoPath from '../images/logo.png';
let html = `<img src="${logoPath}" alt="ACME logo">`;
```

When you require an image file, Webpack copies it into your output directory and returns the final, public path to that file.

**If u need using it from a templates:**

You need to install file-loader to use copyFiles()

```
yarn add file-loader@^6.0.0 --dev
```

then enable it in webpack.config.js:

```
.copyFiles({
    from: './assets/images',
    //optional target path, relative to the output dir
    //to: 'images/[path][name].[ext]',

    //if versioning is enabled, add the file hash too
    to: 'images/[path][name].[hash:8].[ext]',
    //only copy files matching this pattern
    //pattern: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg)$/
})
```

then use it in your twig template:

```
<img src="{{ asset('build/images/logo.png') }}" alt="ACME logo">
```

more details in [Symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/copy-files.html) documentation

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `CopyWebpackPlugin` to do this. You can read [this post](https://hugo-soltys.com/blog/how-to-handle-image-assets-with-symfony-4) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, sadly I tried the integrated copyFiles, which does - if I'm not mistaken - the same as the `CopyWebpackPlugin`.

Problem here is - when a image is uploaded to my asset directory I want the plugin automatically copy it to the /public/build folder, without running encore - which is not the case.

Comment: I don't think you are supposed to upload in the `asset` directory. According to [the official documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html), you have to upload directly in the `public` directory.

Comment: Nvm, I thought I was supposed to upload the files into the /public/build folder, which will be deleted when I run encore. I just realized that I can use a /public/image folder - which will not be deleted, when running encore.